# Running BioPerl scripts in Wampserver

Tags: perl, wampserver

I am creating a page using wampserver on windows and work it locally. I want to access database Ensemble to obtain some useful info, such as a gene's sequence, and i'm running into the following problem:

I have installed ActivePerl and the API's required and my bioperl script runs perfectly from command prompt.

As fas as the wampserver is concerned, i have modifies httpd.conf in Apache to run perl scripts. A simple perl script (e.g hello world) i can executed through wamp. (i stored id on www and go localhost/hello.pl)

When i want to run the script in wampserver for obtaining the sequence (more complex of course) i get this error:

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/wamp/bin/Perl/lib C:/wamp/bin/Perl/site/lib . C:/src/ensembl/modules) at (eval 8) line 3.
>   Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module hasn't been fully installed,
>   or perhaps the capitalisation of 'mysql' isn't right.
>   Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Proxy, Sponge.
>    at C:/src/ensembl/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/Registry.pm line 1594

In command prompt window the script runs. How can i manage it to run it in wampserver??

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `@INC` array contains all paths that Perl will look at to find modules. Currently, your WAMP Perl looks at these places:

```
C:/wamp/bin/Perl/lib
C:/wamp/bin/Perl/site/lib
.
C:/src/ensembl/modules
```

None of these directories contain a subdirectory `DBD` that in turn contains `mysql.pm`. (Please verify this with a file manager)

You seem to have this module installed with ActivePerl. Try to print out the `@INC` of that perl. If the ActivePerl `@INC` contains paths that are not included in your WAMP perl `@INC` (see above), then you should fix that to use your ActivePerl modules. E.g.

```
use lib 'C:/foo/bar/lib';
```

*before* you `use DBD::mysql`. It might fix the problem.

Comment: ok ,the new problem is Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql in @INC (@INC contains: C:/wamp/bin/Perl/lib C:/wamp/bin/Perl/site/lib . C:/src/ensembl/modules;C:/wamp/bin/Perl/site/lib/DBD/mysql.pm) at C:/wamp/www/seq.pl line 9
Compilation failed in require at C:/wamp/www/seq.pl line 9.

line 9 contains the statement use DBD::mysql;

Comment: @user1681361 Assuming you are using *mod_perl*, you can set the `@INC` once during the Apache startup. Add `PerlSetEnv PERL5LIB C:/foo/bar/lib` to the appropriate config file. And take a look at these [other tips](http://modperlbook.org/html/6-8-1-The-INC-Array-Under-mod_perl.html).